# Function incomplete when plotting

Tags: function, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I just came over a problem while displaying a function.
Mathematica doesnt plot the middle of the function:

```
VoigtDistribution[\[Delta]_, \[Sigma]_] = 
  ParameterMixtureDistribution[
  CauchyDistribution[\[Mu], \[Delta]], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
  NormalDistribution[0, \[Sigma]]];

  F[\[Delta]_, \[Sigma]_, x_] = 
  FullSimplify[PDF[VoigtDistribution[\[Delta], \[Sigma]], x], 
  x \[Element] Reals && \[Sigma] > 0 && \[Delta] > 0 ]

  Plot[{1 - F[1, 0.15, x - 10], 1}, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

I dont know why this appears...
With other parameters, such as F[1,0.5,x-10] or F[0.5,0.15,x-10], it is all right.

This issue also appears at a complete other situation when plotting an interpolated function from a dataset.

Why ist that!??

Edit:
For some reason Mathematica is calculating an imaginary part at this position, which equals 0.
So Re[F[...]] does the trick. But why is Mathematica doing this?

Edit2:[Picture1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27066361/stackoverflow1.jpg)
There is another problem with the Voigtdistribution,but i guess thats just because of the definition [Picture2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27066361/stackoverflow2.jpg)

Comment: `VoigtDistribution` is a built-in symbol in version 9 and it's better not to try to redefine it.  Generally, just avoid using any names starting with capital letters.  That guaranteed to avoid conflict with all packages and builtins in current and future versions.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you mention but `Chop` is the usual way to get rid of those imaginary zeros.

Comment: I got the >VoigtDistribution definition from the documentation (ref/ParameterMixtureDistribution->Applications) and im using version 8
Chop does work when getting some values but it still doesnt work in plots. I'll add a picture in the post.

Comment: It is safe to just use `Re` if you know that the small imaginary parts are due to roundoff errors.  You can also use Mathematica's arbitrary precision arithmetic (not the default machine precision one), which has precision tracking and will usually (but not always) be able to tell that the imaginary parts are smaller than the available precision.  Example: ``Plot[{1 - F[1, 0.15`10, x - 10], 1}, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 10]``  (Note the ``0.15`10`` notation which forces that number to precision 10 as well!)

Comment: I see that the documentation has this definition, but I still don't recommend using names with capital letters.  If you use this particular definition, your code will be broken in version 9.  For your future questions you can consider asking [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) for better faster answers, most Mma users have moved there.